# Can I set up a search box that uses fields?

Tags: search

I would like to set up a special search feature so people could select their search targets by two or more factors, for example

dropdown box [animal] ... 2nd dropdown box [continent]

... so they select the dropdown1 and pick "Lions" and the second dropdown and pick "Canada", so I can bring them up posts that are categorized/tagged with "Lions" and "Canada"

or something like this.

Has anyone done anything similar? Seen it done somewhere? Know a good starting point?

Thanks,
JM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from scratch: There's two theme template files you can use for this:

searchform.php - this is rendered when you add a search widget to a sidebar. Add your dropdown boxes here.

search.php - this is where you'd write your custom Query using the submitted values from the form. The form submits via GET.

Check this out if you're going to code yourself: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

However, you first might want to check out if a plugin would do what you want. I've never had use for anything like this, so I can't speak to how well any plugins work for this type of application, but a quick search popped up with this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-wp-query-search-filter/

Comment: Thank you. Those both look like very good starts! I'm going to look into both.